# AppWidget is not updated even though onUpdate is called

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I post a broadcast to update my widget and its `onUpdate` function is called, I can see it in the logs, but the text remains unchanged - apart from the 1st call to onUpdate, when the widget is created.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("WIDGET", "onUpdate");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_home);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, new Random().nextInt() + "x");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
        Log.d("WIDGET", "updated");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need store the appWidgetId when it create , when you want to update it.
call [appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget(int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews))

im not sure why [partiallyUpdateAppWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#partiallyUpdateAppWidget(int[],%20android.widget.RemoteViews))
 not work. you can read the docs
    appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);